# .Net collection that maintains order and supports search for subset with matching order

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Is there a .Net collection that maintains order and supports search for subset with matching order.

**UPDATE 1**: I developed an approach that works for me and answered my own question below. However I won't mark it as THE answer until I see whether anyone comes up with a better approach.

**UPDATE 2**: Waited a few days; not much traffic and no suggestions, so I went ahead
and marked my answer the the one I implemented.

Use case: I have a collection of objects (strings or integers for instance) in a specific order and I need to determine if another collection is an exact subset of the superset, i.e. order matters, ABC is not the same as CBA

First off, please note that **I’m using SortedSet only to illustrate what I want to accomplish**. It doesn’t do what I need to do. So you can think of this as pseudo code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fleet = new List<string>();
    fleet.Add("MotherShip");

    var motherShip = new SortedSet<string>();
    var motherArray = new string[7] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
    for (int i = 0; i < motherArray.Length; i++)
    {
        motherShip.Add(motherArray[i]);
    }

    var shipOne = new SortedSet<string>();
    var shipOneArray = new string[6] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    for (int i = 0; i < shipOneArray.Length; i++)
    {
        shipOne.Add(shipOneArray[i]);
    }
    // shipOne should NOT be added
    if (!shipOne.IsProperSubsetOf(motherShip)) fleet.Add("ShipOne");

    var shipTwo = new SortedSet<string>();
    var shipTwoArray = new string[6] { "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
    for (int i = 0; i < shipTwoArray.Length; i++)
    {
        shipTwo.Add(shipTwoArray[i]);
    }
    // shipTwo should NOT be added
    if (!shipTwo.IsProperSubsetOf(motherShip)) fleet.Add("ShipTwo");

    var shipThree = new SortedSet<string>();
    var shipThreeArray = new string[5] { "E", "B", "C", "D", "A" };
    for (int i = 0; i < shipThreeArray.Length; i++)
    {
        shipThree.Add(shipThreeArray[i]);
    }
    // shipThree SHOULD BE added
    if (!shipThree.IsProperSubsetOf(motherShip)) fleet.Add("ShipThree");

    Console.WriteLine("Fleet has {0} ships. Press any key to continue.", fleet.Count);
    // Need it to be: Fleet has 2 ships.

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out. To recap the use case: Given an array and a collection of smaller arrays, create a collection of arrays which are not subsets of the larger array where order matters, i.e. { "A", "B", "C" } != { "C", "B", "A" } and the array values are in contiguous indexes in both the superset and subset arrays.

I imagine there are many ways to accomplish this, and my approach may not be the most performant, but the arrays I'm working with are small so this approach will get the job done.

Here's the complete code from the console application:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // This is the master list of IDs - no repeats. Hard coded here for the example.
    var masterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var masterArray = new string[15] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P" };
    for (var i = 0; i < masterArray.Length; i++)
    {
        masterDictionary.Add(masterArray[i], i);
    }

    var uniqueArrays = GetUniqueArrays(masterDictionary);

    Console.WriteLine("Unique array collection has {0} arrays. Press any key to continue.", 
        uniqueArrays.Count);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

/// <summary>
/// Create a collection of arrays which are not subsets of a larger array where order matters,
/// i.e. { "A", "B", "C" } != { "C", "B", "A" } and the array values are in contiguous 
/// indexes in both the superset and subset arrays.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private static List<string[]> GetUniqueArrays(Dictionary<string, int> masterDictionary)
{
    // This is the list of subsets I'll return
    var uniqueArrays = new List<string[]>();

    // This the superset of IDs, no repeats. We'll use an ordered dictionary because
    // we need to find values in it by index.
    var supersetDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();
    var supersetArray = new string[7] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
    for (var i = 0; i < supersetArray.Length; i++)
    {
        var value = 0;
        masterDictionary.TryGetValue(supersetArray[i], out value);
        supersetDictionary.Add(supersetArray[i], value);
    }

    // The superset array will always be in the list we return.
    uniqueArrays.Add(supersetArray);

    // Hard code some subsets and add them to a collection
    var subsets = new List<string[]>();

    // Is a subset
    var subsetOne = new string[6] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    subsets.Add(subsetOne);

    // Is a subset
    var subsetTwo = new string[6] { "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
    subsets.Add(subsetTwo);

    // Is a subset
    var subsetThree = new string[3] { "B", "C", "D" };
    subsets.Add(subsetThree);

    // Is NOT a subset
    var subsetFour = new string[3] { "D", "C", "B" };
    subsets.Add(subsetFour);

    // Check if the subsetArray is a subset of the supersetArray. If it is not
    // then add it to the list of unique subsets
    foreach (var subset in subsets)
    {
        if (!CheckIsSubset(masterDictionary, supersetDictionary, subset)) 
            uniqueArrays.Add(subset);
    }

    return uniqueArrays;
}

/// <summary>
/// Determine an array is a subset of a larger array where order matters,
/// i.e. { "A", "B", "C" } != { "C", "B", "A" } and the array values are in 
/// contiguous indexes in both the superset and subset arrays.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="masterSet"></param>
/// <param name="superset"></param>
/// <param name="subset"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static bool CheckIsSubset(Dictionary<string, int> masterSet, 
    OrderedDictionary superset, string[] subset)
{
    var supersetIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < subset.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        // Get the masterDictionary value for the first ID in the subsetArray
        var idValue = -1;
        masterSet.TryGetValue(subset[i], out idValue);
        if (idValue >= 0)
        {
            // Next determine if the first ID in the subset array is in the superset.
            if (supersetIndex == -1)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < superset.Count; j++)
                {
                    // Get the ID at index j from the superset and compare it to subset ID
                    var supersetId = superset.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(j).Key.ToString();
                    var subsetId = subset[i];
                    if (subsetId == supersetId)
                    {
                        // This is the index in the superset from where we want to start our comparison
                        supersetIndex = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // The first ID is not in the superset so we know the array we're testing is not
                // a subset.
                if (supersetIndex == -1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var error = string.Format("The ID {0} is not in the master list.", idValue);
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        // We have a match. Next we want to step through the subset array.
        // We next test for matches in the adjoining indexes
        supersetIndex++;
        if (superset.Count >= supersetIndex)
        {
            // Get the superset value at this index and compare it to the subset value
            var supersetKey = superset.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(supersetIndex).Key.ToString();
            var subsetValue = subset[i + 1];
            if (subsetValue != supersetKey) return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // The supersetIndex is at or greater than the length of the superset array
            // so our subset is unique.
            return false;                    
        }
    }

    // The array we're examining is a subset of the larger array
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SortedSet is not a bad idea.

```
SortedSet SearchedArray = new Sorted { ... } // What you are looking for
SortedSet ExtractArray = MotherArray.GetViewBetween(SearchedArray.Min,SearchedArray.Max) ;
bool found=ExtractArray.Count==SearchedArray.Count;
for (int i=0;i<SearchedArray.count && found; i++) found=ExtractArray[i]==SearchedArray[i] ;
```

Comment: Thanks Graffito. I think min and max won't work. The actual superset collection I need to check will consist of integers (ID values), ex. { 1245, 9485, 2458 }. What's more, it seems SortedSet will do exactly what the name suggests: adding A, D, F, E will create a set A, D, E, F

Comment: SortedSet.Min and SortedSet.Max are equivalent to SortedSet[0] and SortedSet[SortedSet.Count-1]. If you want to keep the ADFE order, then SortedSet is not appropriate.